# How can I add all the elements of a Matrix using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function called check_sum that adds all the elements of an 2d array.

Grid is a 2d array, and grid_shape is 1024x1024.

I'm trying to use the numpy.matrix.sum function, but after several attempts I don't know how to implement it, it always gives me another value.

```
def check_sum(grid):
  xmax, ymax = grid_shape
  s=0
  for i in range(xmax):
    for j in range(ymax):
      s += grid[i][j]
  return s
```

Comment: That's exactly what `np.matrix.sum` does; if `grid` is an `np.matrix`, then `grid.sum` calculates the sum of all its entries.

Comment: The problem is that `grid = np.array(grid)`, and I don't know what function use for a 2d array.

Comment: can you shows us how you use `np.matrix.sum`?

Comment: Ok, I have already solved it, the problem was that I treated grid as a matrix and it was a 2d array. I used this: ```s = np.sum(grid)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `grid.sum()` and it will return the sum of all the entries in your array, no matter if it is a 2d or a 3d array. `Sum()` is a general numpy method and it works both for matrices and arrays.[here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)